# Docker with third party software

Tags: docker

I have a very basic question. Does Docker bundle even the third party software libraries in the container? For e.g., lets say my application has a third party software, can I bundle it in the container and ship it from Dev to QA/Test server? Do I need this third party software installed on the QA/Test server also or will Docker container take care of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker instance can be seen as lightweight virtual machine. It has it's own filesystem and CPU/memory resources.

To run program inside docker instance you need to have all it's dependencies installed inside docker instance. So yes, you can bundle all in single container and ship to other servers.

Also, you can share part of filesystem from host system with docker instance. In this case to transfer such instance on other server you need to take care of transferring all dependencies that are shared from host. But this is not default behaviour of Docker, just one of it's features.